# Exceptions in constructors

Tags: java, exception, constructor

In C++, the lifetime of an object begins when the constructor finishes successfully. Inside the constructor, the object does not exist yet.

> Q: What does emitting an exception from a constructor mean?
>
> A: It means that construction has failed, the object never existed, its lifetime never began. [[source](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm)]

My question is: Does the same hold true for Java? What happens, for example, if I hand `this` to another object, and then my constructor fails?

```
Foo()
{
    Bar.remember(this);
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Is this well-defined? Does `Bar` now have a reference to a non-object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The object exists, but it's not been initialized properly.

This can happen whenever `this` leaks during construction (not just when you throw an exception).

It's a very problematic situation, because some commonly assumed guarantees don't hold true in this situation (for example `final` fields could seem to change their value during construction).

Therefore you should definitely avoid leaking `this` in the constructor.

[This IBM developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html) describes the precautions to take when constructing objects and the reasoning behind those precautions. While the article discusses the subject in the light of multi-threading, you can have similar problems in a single-threaded environment when unknown/untrusted code gets a reference to `this` during construction.

Comment: +1 - but "leaking" is called (unsafe) "publishing" in this case; e.g. in Bloch.  Also it would be a good idea to explain this in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

You should never open resources like a file writer in your constructor. Create a init method instead and do it from there. Then you're safe.

Comment: *"Then you're safe"*.  That statement is patently false!! There are **lots** of other things that can cause exceptions in a constructor; e.g. illegal argument, NPE, array index, etc, and even stack overflow or out of memory errors.

Comment: That's good advice but there are other cases where you might want a constructor to fail. For example, I want a parallel iterator as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137944/best-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-simultaneously so I want to check the lists are the same size at construction time.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not exception safe and neither would be exception safe in C++. It's same bug regardless of the language you use.