# Java: Best/elegant way to iterate over 2 lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iteration

Assume I have a `List<SomeObject> a`.
Now also assume that I have another `List<SomeProcessor> b`.
Each `SomeProcessor` uses `a` for its processing.

Besides:

```
int idx = 0;   
for(SomeProcessor o:b){  
    o2 = a.get(idx);  
    o.doSomething(o2);  
    idx++;   
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: does a support Iterable interface?

Comment: No.It is just a custom object.How would that help?I mean should there be one?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8104205/1029272   Easy to implement, and works a treat. I got it up and running within the last 5 minutes to try it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to iterate over two lists simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137944/best-way-to-iterate-over-two-lists-simultaneously)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public interface Processor<T> {
    public void process(T object);
}
```

And then a helper method:

```
public static <T> void processAll(Collection<T> items, Collection<? extends Processor<T>> processors) {
    Iterator<T> i = items.iterator();
    Iterator<? extends Processor<T>> p = processors.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext() && p.hasNext())
        p.next().process(i.next()); 
}
```

You could put that helper method on the class which uses it, if there is only one (and make it `private`), or put it a utility class which is shared by the entire program.

Of course there are other ways to code `processAll`; for example, you could use a `for` loop on one of the collections. But in any case, breaking this low-level code out into a helper method will make your higher-level code cleaner and less "noisy". And if you are doing something similar in multiple parts of the program, they can share the helper method.

Comment: I don't want to process it like that.I need to process each object once by 1 processor

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan:Yes they are always same size

Comment: @Alex D:So you suggest essentially to use the 2 iterators of the `lists` simultaneously, right?

Comment: @Jim, you could use a `for` loop and an iterator, or 2 iterators. In either case, the biggest thing you can do to make your code cleaner, is to move this detailed, low-level code into a helper method with a meaningful name.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Java doesn't have closures... you could write a very nice, general-purpose method for "iterating over two lists and doing something to each pair" if it did.

Answer (score 1):

If you can generate a `Map<SomeObject, SomeProcessor>` instead of two lists, then it'll be elegant. This may not apply, but I'll just give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with this simpler way :

```
int idx = 0;
while(idx<a.size() && idx<b.size()){   
    b.get(idx).doSomething(a.get(idx++));
}
```